# cakePHP: $this->Form->input() - How to set a select default option

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In my view I have:

```
echo $this->Form->input('category_parent_id');
```

and it outputs:

```
<option value="1">category name 1</option>
<option value="2">category name 2</option>
...
```

but how do I tell it input() that I want a default option like so?:

```
<option value="">select a category</option>
<option value="1">category name 1</option>
<option value="2">category name 2</option>
...
```

nvm, found it:

```
echo $this->Form->input('category_parent_id', array('empty' => 'Select a parent category'));
```

Comment: Please consider posting the solution as proper answer for future reference.

Answer (score 15):

Your question is a little vague, but you can do the following to select a default option...

```
echo $this->Form->input('category_parent_id', array('default' => 'id_of_default_val'));
```

**EDIT**

Per your edit, to include an empty default option, do this as documented in the CakePHP Form Helper...

```
echo $this->Form->input('category_parent_id', array('empty' => 'choose one'));
```